# Open Layer remove passed line when marker moves

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, openlayers-6

I'm working with **open layer** I have stumbled on a problem.

Here is what am I trying to achieve is to remove passed line, when the marker moves.

To explain a bit more, check bellow example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

When clicking start animation, the marker moves, but **the yellow line** that marker passed by, is stayed, I would like to remove that line behind the marker when the marker moves.

How can that be done with OpenLayers?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from [the example referenced](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html), one option would be to add a new line `Feature`, then update its coordinates to remove those which have already been traversed

- add a new `Polyline`:

  ```
  // new line feature (polyline) 
  var lineCoords = route.getCoordinates();
  var lineFeature = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'line',
    geometry: route.clone()
  });
  ```
- add the new feature to the vector layer:

  ```
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
      features: [geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker, lineFeature],
  ```
- inside the moveFeature function, update the line's coordinates to remove those already traversed:

  ```
  var moveFeature = function (event) {
      // ...
      var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[index]);
      coords=routeCoords.slice(index);
      lineFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(coords);
  ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.4.3_feature-move-animation_removePolyline.html)

[image: screenshot of resulting map in the middle of animating]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This long string is placed here due to jsFiddle limitations.
// It is usually loaded with AJAX.
var polyline = [
  'hldhx@lnau`BCG_EaC??cFjAwDjF??uBlKMd@}@z@??aC^yk@z_@se@b[wFdE??wFfE}N',
  'fIoGxB_I\\gG}@eHoCyTmPqGaBaHOoD\\??yVrGotA|N??o[N_STiwAtEmHGeHcAkiA}^',
  'aMyBiHOkFNoI`CcVvM??gG^gF_@iJwC??eCcA]OoL}DwFyCaCgCcCwDcGwHsSoX??wI_E',
  'kUFmq@hBiOqBgTwS??iYse@gYq\\cp@ce@{vA}s@csJqaE}{@iRaqE{lBeRoIwd@_T{]_',
  'Ngn@{PmhEwaA{SeF_u@kQuyAw]wQeEgtAsZ}LiCarAkVwI}D??_}RcjEinPspDwSqCgs@',
  'sPua@_OkXaMeT_Nwk@ob@gV}TiYs[uTwXoNmT{Uyb@wNg]{Nqa@oDgNeJu_@_G}YsFw]k',
  'DuZyDmm@i_@uyIJe~@jCg|@nGiv@zUi_BfNqaAvIow@dEed@dCcf@r@qz@Egs@{Acu@mC',
  'um@yIey@gGig@cK_m@aSku@qRil@we@{mAeTej@}Tkz@cLgr@aHko@qOmcEaJw~C{w@ka',
  'i@qBchBq@kmBS{kDnBscBnFu_Dbc@_~QHeU`IuyDrC_}@bByp@fCyoA?qMbD}{AIkeAgB',
  'k_A_A{UsDke@gFej@qH{o@qGgb@qH{`@mMgm@uQus@kL{_@yOmd@ymBgwE}x@ouBwtA__',
  'DuhEgaKuWct@gp@cnBii@mlBa_@}|Asj@qrCg^eaC}L{dAaJ_aAiOyjByH{nAuYu`GsAw',
  'Xyn@ywMyOyqD{_@cfIcDe}@y@aeBJmwA`CkiAbFkhBlTgdDdPyiB`W}xDnSa}DbJyhCrX',
  'itAhT}x@bE}Z_@qW_Kwv@qKaaAiBgXvIm}A~JovAxCqW~WanB`XewBbK{_A`K}fBvAmi@',
  'xBycBeCauBoF}}@qJioAww@gjHaPopA_NurAyJku@uGmi@cDs[eRaiBkQstAsQkcByNma',
  'CsK_uBcJgbEw@gkB_@ypEqDoqSm@eZcDwjBoGw`BoMegBaU_`Ce_@_uBqb@ytBwkFqiT_',
  'fAqfEwe@mfCka@_eC_UmlB}MmaBeWkkDeHwqAoX}~DcBsZmLcxBqOwqE_DkyAuJmrJ\\o',
  '~CfIewG|YibQxBssB?es@qGciA}RorAoVajA_nAodD{[y`AgPqp@mKwr@ms@umEaW{dAm',
  'b@umAw|@ojBwzDaaJsmBwbEgdCsrFqhAihDquAi`Fux@}_Dui@_eB_u@guCuyAuiHukA_',
  'lKszAu|OmaA{wKm}@clHs_A_rEahCssKo\\sgBsSglAqk@yvDcS_wAyTwpBmPc|BwZknF',
  'oFscB_GsaDiZmyMyLgtHgQonHqT{hKaPg}Dqq@m~Hym@c`EuiBudIabB{hF{pWifx@snA',
  'w`GkFyVqf@y~BkoAi}Lel@wtc@}`@oaXi_C}pZsi@eqGsSuqJ|Lqeb@e]kgPcaAu}SkDw',
  'zGhn@gjYh\\qlNZovJieBqja@ed@siO{[ol\\kCmjMe\\isHorCmec@uLebB}EqiBaCg}',
  '@m@qwHrT_vFps@kkI`uAszIrpHuzYxx@e{Crw@kpDhN{wBtQarDy@knFgP_yCu\\wyCwy',
  'A{kHo~@omEoYmoDaEcPiuAosDagD}rO{{AsyEihCayFilLaiUqm@_bAumFo}DgqA_uByi',
  '@swC~AkzDlhA}xEvcBa}Cxk@ql@`rAo|@~bBq{@``Bye@djDww@z_C_cAtn@ye@nfC_eC',
  '|gGahH~s@w}@``Fi~FpnAooC|u@wlEaEedRlYkrPvKerBfYs}Arg@m}AtrCkzElw@gjBb',
  'h@woBhR{gCwGkgCc[wtCuOapAcFoh@uBy[yBgr@c@iq@o@wvEv@sp@`FajBfCaq@fIipA',
  'dy@ewJlUc`ExGuaBdEmbBpBssArAuqBBg}@s@g{AkB{bBif@_bYmC}r@kDgm@sPq_BuJ_',
  's@{X_{AsK_d@eM{d@wVgx@oWcu@??aDmOkNia@wFoSmDyMyCkPiBePwAob@XcQ|@oNdCo',
  'SfFwXhEmOnLi\\lbAulB`X_d@|k@au@bc@oc@bqC}{BhwDgcD`l@ed@??bL{G|a@eTje@',
  'oS~]cLr~Bgh@|b@}Jv}EieAlv@sPluD{z@nzA_]`|KchCtd@sPvb@wSb{@ko@f`RooQ~e',
  '[upZbuIolI|gFafFzu@iq@nMmJ|OeJn^{Qjh@yQhc@uJ~j@iGdd@kAp~BkBxO{@|QsAfY',
  'gEtYiGd]}Jpd@wRhVoNzNeK`j@ce@vgK}cJnSoSzQkVvUm^rSgc@`Uql@xIq\\vIgg@~k',
  'Dyq[nIir@jNoq@xNwc@fYik@tk@su@neB}uBhqEesFjoGeyHtCoD|D}Ed|@ctAbIuOzqB',
  '_}D~NgY`\\um@v[gm@v{Cw`G`w@o{AdjAwzBh{C}`Gpp@ypAxn@}mAfz@{bBbNia@??jI',
  'ab@`CuOlC}YnAcV`@_^m@aeB}@yk@YuTuBg^uCkZiGk\\yGeY}Lu_@oOsZiTe[uWi[sl@',
  'mo@soAauAsrBgzBqgAglAyd@ig@asAcyAklA}qAwHkGi{@s~@goAmsAyDeEirB_{B}IsJ',
  'uEeFymAssAkdAmhAyTcVkFeEoKiH}l@kp@wg@sj@ku@ey@uh@kj@}EsFmG}Jk^_r@_f@m',
  '~@ym@yjA??a@cFd@kBrCgDbAUnAcBhAyAdk@et@??kF}D??OL'
].join('');

var route = /** @type {import("../src/ol/geom/LineString.js").default} */ (new ol.format.Polyline({
  factor: 1e6,
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
}));

var routeCoords = route.getCoordinates();
var routeLength = routeCoords.length;

var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route,
});
var lineCoords = route.getCoordinates();
var lineFeature = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'line',
  geometry: route.clone()
});
var geoMarker = /** @type Feature<import("../src/ol/geom/Point").default> */ (new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0]),
}));
var startMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0]),
});
var endMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[routeLength - 1]),
});

var styles = {
  'line': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: "blue",
    }),
  }),
  'route': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8],
    }),
  }),
  'icon': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png',
    }),
  }),
  'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({ // CircleStyle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  }),
};

var animating = false;
var speed, now;
var speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
var startButton = document.getElementById('start-animation');

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
    features: [ /* routeFeature, */ geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker, lineFeature],
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    // hide geoMarker if animation is active
    if (animating && feature.get('type') === 'geoMarker') {
      return null;
    }
    return styles[feature.get('type')];
  },
});

var key = 'otwSpfI7kCJve6AMTcr0';
var attributions =
  '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> ' +
  '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>';

var center = [-5639523.95, -3501274.52];
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19,
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: attributions,
        url: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/hybrid/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=' + key,
        tileSize: 512,
      }),
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
});

var moveFeature = function(event) {
  var vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(event);
  var frameState = event.frameState;

  if (animating) {
    var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now;
    // here the trick to increase speed is to jump some indexes
    // on lineString coordinates
    var index = Math.round((speed * elapsedTime) / 1000);

    if (index >= routeLength) {
      stopAnimation(true);
      return;
    }

    var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[index]);
    coords = routeCoords.slice(index);
    lineFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(coords);
    var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);
    vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, styles.geoMarker);
  }
  // tell OpenLayers to continue the postrender animation
  map.render();
};

function startAnimation() {
  if (animating) {
    stopAnimation(false);
  } else {
    animating = true;
    now = new Date().getTime();
    speed = speedInput.value;
    startButton.textContent = 'Cancel Animation';
    // hide geoMarker
    geoMarker.setStyle(null);
    // just in case you pan somewhere else
    map.getView().setCenter(center);
    vectorLayer.on('postrender', moveFeature);
    map.render();
  }
}

/**
 * @param {boolean} ended end of animation.
 */
function stopAnimation(ended) {
  animating = false;
  startButton.textContent = 'Start Animation';

  // if animation cancelled set the marker at the beginning
  var coord = ended ? routeCoords[routeLength - 1] : routeCoords[0];
  var geometry = geoMarker.getGeometry();
  geometry.setCoordinates(coord);
  //remove listener
  vectorLayer.un('postrender', moveFeature);
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', startAnimation, false);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<label for="speed">
      speed:&nbsp;
      <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
    </label>
<button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>
```